# Bash. Перевод строки перед выполнением каждой команды

Tags: bash, .bashrc

Мне нужна противоположность PROMT_COMMAND. Дело в том, что я хочу отделить приглашение PS1 от окружающей его информации символами перевода строки "\n". Сделать это нужно не только сверху, но и **снизу**. Чтобы отделить PS1 от результата выполнения предыдущей команды (то есть сверху) - достаточно всего лишь в PROMT_COMMAND добавить echo "\n". А вот как это сделать снизу - я без понятия. Нужно добавить автоматический перевод строки после ввода команды и нажатия Enter. Образно говоря - это должно выглядеть так:

```
\n (перевод строки)
user@pc~$ какая-то команда [Enter]
\n (здесь тоже нужен автоматический перевод)
результат выполнения этой команды
```

Подскажите пожалуйста каким способом можно этого достичь

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/175799/454489

Comment: Спасибо, PS0 мне помогло